# How to set pointer to CGColor object nil / NULL?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, memory-management

I have the following property:

```
@property (nonatomic) CGColorRef *strokeColor;
```

At a certain point in my program, I set it to nil. Then later on in my program I check to see if it's nil:

```
CGColorRef strokeColor = (*graphicPath.strokeColor != nil) ? CGColorRetain(*graphicPath.strokeColor)  : nil;
```

I'm getting a bad access at this line. I've also tried using NULL and still no dice. It works when there is something stored in it and it's not nil / NULL.

How can I get this to work?

Comment: Whether I don't understand what you're trying to do or your syntax is definitely wrong. Why are you using indirection (*) in the comparison?  Remember CGColorRef is already a reference, you don't need to use it as a pointer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to change

```
(*graphicPath.strokeColor != nil)
```

to

```
(graphicPath.strokeColor != nil)
```

(got rid of the asterisk).

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `*` from the definition of your strokeColor (which is already a pointer because it is a `CGColorRef`) and also from the graphicPath, it may solve your issue.

Comment: Sorry, you were indeed faster than me @alex-unstable.

Answer (score 0):

Check my comment above:

> Whether I don't understand what you're trying to do or your syntax is
>   definitely wrong. Why are you using indirection (*) in the comparison?
>   Remember CGColorRef is already a reference, you don't need to use it
>   as a pointer!

And accept this an answer if helped you.